# Como insertar tipos de fuentes sin tener que instalarlas en la computadora.?

Tags: html, css

Deseo saber como incluir tipos de fuentes sin tener que instalarla en el ordenador y que cuando la copie en otra pc se vea la fuente.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y si no esta en la pc, como va a saber como dibujar cada letra el navegador? de algun lado la tiene que bajar, a eso te referis?

Comment: Convierte los textos en imagenes?

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro de haber entendido perfectamente bien pero puedes tratar utilizar google fonts.

Algo asi:

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Nunito|Pacifico" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;">Tipo de fuente NUNITO</h1>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;">Tipo de fuente LOBSTER</h1>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;">Tipo de fuente PACIFICO</h1>

</body>
```

Te daria como resultado esto:

[image: Tipos de fuente]

La otra persona necesita tener confección a internet para que funcione, de otra manera tendrías que hacer referencia a las tipografías de manera local.

```
<head>

<style>
@font-face { font-family: Lobster; src: url('Lobster-Regular.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Nunito; src: url('Nunito-Regular.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Pacifico; src: url('Pacifico-Regular.ttf'); } 

</style>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Nunito';">Tipo de fuente NUNITO</h1>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Lobster';">Tipo de fuente LOBSTER</h1>
<h1 style="font-family: 'Pacifico';">Tipo de fuente PACIFICO</h1>

</body>
```

Las fuentes deberían estar en donde lo especifiques, en este caso, en el mismo lugar donde esta tu archivo index o tu archivo CSS si utilizas uno.
[image: Fuentes locales]